# What does App Store Browse mean on itunes connect?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, itunesconnect-analytics

I have been looking at the analytics on iTunes connect. And there is App Store Browse and App Store Search. Don't they both mean the same thing?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 1):

If you hover on the text, there will be a small '?' icon and if you hover over it you can see a more detailed explanation on each metric.
[image]

And for your question -

**App Store Browse** - Customers viewed your app or tapped to download it for the first time while browsing certain sections of the App Store, including Top Charts and Categories.

**App Store Search** - Customers viewed your app or tapped to download it for the first time from Search on the App Store. Includes Search Ads in App Store search.